# How to Define Enum as Query Params in OpenAPI Spec

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

I want to define an enum value in the query string parameter of a function in an OpenAPI specification.

Here is an example of how I specify the parameter in my OpenAPI specification (yaml):

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: Vends sodas
  version: 1.0.0
  title: VendingMachineService
paths:
  /soda/{bill}:
    get:
      summary: Provides a soda for a provided amount of money
      description: Provides a soda for a provided amount of money
      operationId: getSoda
      parameters:
      - name: bill
        in: path
        description: Money (e.g. one, two, five)
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bill"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Result"
        "404":
          description: Templates for Source not found
servers:
- url: http://localhost:8080/
components:
  schemas:
    Bill:
      type: string
      enum:
      - one
      - two
      - five
    Result:
      type: string
```

The key part of the OpenAPI spec is that I define the enum in a schema object at the bottom, type string, and refer to it in the parameters section of the function, also defining it as part of the path /{bill}

I then use openapi-generator to generate the spring server:

```
openapi-generator generate -i ~/vending-machine.yaml -g spring -o ~/output
```

I then spin up the server (importing the project into Intellij and running in a spring-boot configuration) and go to localhost:8080/ to open the Swagger UI. I try to exercise the api and get the following error:

> {   "timestamp": "2019-03-29T15:43:14.737Z",   "status": 400,
>   "error": "Bad Request",   "message": "Failed to convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.openapitools.model.Bill';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
>   @io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam @javax.validation.Valid
>   @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   org.openapitools.model.Bill] for value 'null'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
>   org.openapitools.model.Bill.null",   "path": "/soda/%7Bbill%7D" }

(501 Not Implemented expected)

What is the proper way to define the query params & enum in the OpenAPI spec to use enum values?

Comment: I would suggest you create an issue via http://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new so that the community can help you out.